# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException using random int

Tags: java, arrays, random, while-loop, integer

I try to use this method for create random numbers and save that random number in a array

```
int[] ndigitos = new int[313];
public int  Imagenes(int cont) {


    do {

        nuevo = r.nextInt(313);

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {

            if (nuevo == ndigitos[i])
                aux = 1;
        }

        if (aux == 0) {
            // agregar en la siguiente posicion el nuevo numero
            ndigitos[total] = nuevo;
            total++;
        }

        aux = 0;
    } while (total < 313);

    return ndigitos[cont];

}
```

but i have this error when run my app

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=313; index=313
at com.goldapp.imagenesparawhatsapp.Metodos.Imagenes(Metodos.java:97)
at com.goldapp.imagenesparawhatsapp.Main.onClick(Main.java:139)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You're going past the end of the array by 1-  the array is 313 long, and you're accessing index 313-  you can only legally access [0,312].  I can't tell where it is though, because many of your variables are set elsewhere, like cont and total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to modify your while condition to be (total < 312)

Comment: I think this is not the cause of the error because the last one of total<313 is 312 which is legal index.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the array is 313, from the error message you are passing an index that is 313, but you can only access up to 312, since the array starts with a 0 and not a 1.

So from what I see, your error can come from two places, this line:

`ndigitos[total] = nuevo;`

or this line:

```
ndigitos[cont];
```

I cannot see where you are declaring and setting the initial value of total, you can probably find the problem there. 
Or check what value you are passing as a parameter cont, it might be 313

Hope it helps